# How to access Delete Row function in a Multivalued row for a Eureka form

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I would like to access the delete row function in the eureka form but I couldn't find how to do it.  The reason is that I have an i variable that keeps track of how many rows I have and because of that my form breaks when a row is deleted.

This is how my implementation currently looks in my code:

```
+++ MultivaluedSection(multivaluedOptions: [.Reorder, .Insert, .Delete], header: "Exercises", footer: "List of Exercises for workout"){
            $0.addButtonProvider = {section in
                return ButtonRow(){
                    $0.title = "Add Another Exercise"
                    self.i+=1
                }
            }
            $0.multivaluedRowToInsertAt = { index in
                return TextRow() {
                    $0.title = "Exercise \(self.i) Name"
                    $0.tag = "Exercise \(self.i) Name"
                    self.i+=1
                }
            }
            $0 <<< TextRow(){ //change this to SuggestionRow later
                $0.title = "Exercise \(self.i) Name"
                $0.tag = "Exercise \(self.i) Name"
                $0.add(ruleSet: strictRules)
            }
        }
```

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
$0.multivaluedRowToDeleteAt = { index in
   self.i-=1
 }
```

Does something like this exist? If not, is there any other way to get the number of rows for this multivalued section at submission time?